# Why does my SFML keep crashing when passing sf::Texture as an argument into a function

Tags: c++, sfml

When I try to pass a Texture as an argument into a function, then run the program, I get a "*Program.exe* has stopped working" message on the window as soon as I run it.

I can create the texture inside the function, and it will then function, however this destroys the texture at the end of the function, so all I get is a white box.

```
void create_sprite(sf::Texture texty, float lenScale, float widScale, int houseNum, int fieldNum){
    sf::Sprite* spritey = new sf::Sprite(texty);
    spritey -> setScale(lenScale, widScale);
    spritey -> setPosition(fieldWidCoor[houseNum-1][fieldNum-1], fieldLenCoor[houseNum-1][fieldNum-1]);
    houseList.push_back(*spritey);
}

Then in main{}

    sf::Texture grassTex;
    grassTex.loadFromFile("images/field-grass.png");
    create_sprite(grassTex, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 1);


It should cause all calls to the function to create another sprite with the same Texture, but all I get is the crash.
```

Comment: *It is important to note that the sf::Sprite instance doesn't copy the texture that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a sf::Texture must not be destroyed while it is used by a sf::Sprite.* from sfml reference.

Comment: also you never check whether texture has been loaded or not

Comment: You should not be creating your sprite dynamically there if you are simply going to copy it into a vector. Just declare it as a local variable: `sf::Sprite spritey(texty);` Or even use *emplace*: `houseList.emplace_back(texty);`

Comment: I'm creating it dynamically because I will be creating quite a number of sprites using the same texture, and I don't want to initialize them all one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the sf::Sprite instance keeps a reference to the texture it uses. So an sf::Texture cannot be destroyed while it's being used by an sf::Sprite, which is what you are trying to do and causing the error.